# How to transfer data from a Deque to a SortedSet in Java

Tags: java, deque, sortedset

I get a `Deque<Element> deque` and I want to transfer all the elements to the other structure: `SortedSet<Element> sortedSet`.

And the sequence of elements in sortedSet is just as same as the sequences in which the elements are popped from deque.

For example: if all the elements are popped from `deque` in a sequence: `E01, E02, ..., E10`.
The sequence of elements stored in `sortedSet` are also `E01, E02, ..., E10`.

I don't know how to override the comparator to let the elements store in such a sequence.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Why use a `SortedSet` then? Why not just use a simple `ArrayList`. It would be easy to use and would serve the purpose as well.

Comment: Wait, do you want natural ordering iteration order or insertion iteration order? If the latter, you should use a `LinkedHashSet`, not a `SortedSet`

Comment: because another function just accept a sorted set as one of its parameters and I cannot change the interface of that function.

Comment: @fge, a sortedSet can be implemented by a TreeSet. And I have to create a SortedSet object because of the context.

Comment: In your example, are elements in the `Deque` always in natural order when you pop from it or can they be any order?

Comment: @fge, I want to store all the elements in the sequence that when all elements from Deque are popped in one time.

Comment: OK, and what are your difficulties with the `Comparator`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Jane, I wrote a simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                return 1;
            }
        });
        Deque<Integer> deq = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        deq.add(5);
        deq.add(1);
        deq.add(3);
        set.addAll(deq);
        System.out.println(deq); // 5,1,3
    }
```

The comparator should always `return 1` this way the order stays the same, if this was your question.
**Warning:** this solution violates the `Comparable` and `Set` contract. Use it with caution.

Comment: I think your method is the correct one. Thx, Tomas.

Comment: And i want to ask if the deq becomes empty after 'set.addAll(deq)'?

Comment: No, you have to call `deq.clear();` Accept the answer please, if it works.

Comment: Uh no, the `Comparable` contract is broken here

Comment: So this comparator will tell me 5 > 1, but also 1 > 5 if I compare with arguments reversed? Cool. Violates `The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T, T) . Just use a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain insertion order.

Comment: This is really not the right way to do this.  It relies on the sorting being implemented in a particular way.  Maybe it works for certain `Deque`s, but there's no guarantee of anything if you go around breaking the contracts of the interfaces that you're using.  TomasZ, I really don't think you should have pressured Jane to accept this.

Comment: You are right @fge, also the `Set` contract is broken, but she asked for a `Comparator` which creates a List. I don't know the API she is using, I just provided an answer. She wrote, she needs a `SortedSet<Element>`. I am sorry, I didn't want to pressure anyone.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is most bizarre. You expect to have a `SortedSet` with elements in iteration order...

Here is a bizarre solution to this bizarre problem:

```
// final is CRITICAL here
final List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>(deque);
deque.clear();

final Comparator<Element> cmp = new Comparator<>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final Element a, final Element b)
    {
        return Integer.compare(list.indexOf(a), list.indexOf(b));
    }
}

return new TreeSet<>(list, cmp);
```

**HOWEVER**: this will only work reliably if no two elements in the `Deque` are `.equals()`!
But this is the best you can do given the inherent incompatibility of requirements. All in all, I suspect a XY problem..

---

There *is* a way to make that reliable but this requires that you use Guava:

```
final Equivalence<Object> eq = Equivalence.identity();

final Function<Element, Equivalence.Wrapper<Object>> f = new Function<>()
{
    @Override
    public Equivalence.Wrapper<Object> apply(final Element input)
    {
        return eq.wrap(input);
    }
}

final List<Element> list = Lists.newArrayList(deque);
deque.clear();

final List<Equivalence.Wrapper<Object>> wrapped = Lists.transform(list, f);

final Comparator<Element> cmp = new Comparator<>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final Element a, final Element b)
    {
        return Integer.compare(wrapped.indexOf(f(a)),
            wrapped.indexOf(f(b)));
    }
};

return new TreeSet<>(list, cmp);
```

Comment: So are all the elements in sortedSet in the sequence which I mentioned above if I just use deque as a parameter of the constructor of TreeSet?

Comment: What you didn't tell yet is what order you really expect to have! This is really unclear what you want. Does `Foo` implement `Comparable` or doesn't it? If it does, do you expect to return a set with elements in natural order or insertion order?

Comment: This is the best answer.  A very creative way of working round the seemingly inconsistent requirements.

Comment: @DavidWallace in fact this can be made reliable, but my god it's ugly

Answer (score 0):

As fge already stated, you need a `LinkedHashSet`, a collection which keeps the insertion order:

```
Set<Element> convertToSet(Deque<Element> dq)
{
LinkedHashSet<Element> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<Element>():
while(!dq.isEmpty())
{
lhs.add(dq.peekFirst());
}

return lhs;
}
```

Comment: `peekFirst` does not remove an element. You need `pollFirst` or `removeFirst` if you want to remove and return the first element. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: Unfortunately, `LinkedHashSet` doesn't implement `SortedSet`, which was one of the requirements.

Comment: True, however that requirement was probably based on the idea he wanted to have the Set "sorted" in a certain way (iteration order) and thus thinking he needs `SortedSet`. Though perhaps I'm assuming too many things here.

Comment: Maybe.  I actually interpreted Jane's comment to mean that she was going to pass this structure into a method with a parameter of type `SortedSet<Element>`, but maybe I misunderstood her.

Comment: Of course my answer assumes that one refrains from using necessarily a SortedSet.